# Ошибки работы в Brackets с jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, brackets

[image: Скриншот из Brackets]

Пытаясь использовать `jQuery` в `Brackets` получаю следующую ошибку:

> jQuery was used befor it was defined.

Была как-то такая же проблема с другими типами файлов, и лечилось расширениями. В этом случае нет расширений в менеджере.

Comment: Возможно Вы сперва подключили этот файл, а потом сам jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это косяк brackets. Почему то brackets находит несуществующие косяки в javascript коде. Скачайте расширение brackets-eslint и все пройдёт.